# Change CSS style for all <div> in a class with a timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, settimeout, opacity

I have many `div`

```
.led{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 1;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 5px;
    opacity: 0;
}
<div class="led" id="id1"></div>
<div class="led" id="id2"></div>
<div class="led" id="id3"></div>
```

I want set `opacity` to all but one by one with a delay of 1 second between each. I tried with this function but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var leds = $(".led");
    for (var i=0; i<leds.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function (){
        alert();
        $('#' + leds[i]).css('opacity' , '1');
        }, 1000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what doesn't work? Please see [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Mike is correct that you need to give a bit more details to your question. However I did notice your IDs are `id1, id2, id3` and your js is selecting `id0, id1, id2` because your `i` variable starts at 0. Try changing `$('#' + leds[i]).css('opacity' , '1');`, to `$('#' + leds[i+1]).css('opacity' , '1');`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code:

```js
var leds = $(".led");
for (var i = 0; i < leds.length; i++) {
  (function(idx) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#' + leds[idx].id).css('opacity', '1');
    }, 1000 * idx);
  })(i)
}
```

```css
.led {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  padding:15px;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="led" id="id1">TEST 1</div>
<div class="led" id="id2">TEST 2</div>
<div class="led" id="id3">TEST 4</div>
```

Issues with your code:

- Variable `i` always refers to `3` inside `setTimeout` as it is bound to the same variable outside of the function. We can fix that using an IIFE and passing the `i` to that function as param.
- `leds[i]` refers to a DOM element, it does not represent an id for that element. Thus `$('#' + leds[i])` does nothing.
- Also, `setTimeout` time needs to be multiple with `idx` counter so that they do not display all at once but after a delay of 1000ms.

You can also try this transition effect:

```js
var leds = $(".led");
for (var i = 0; i < leds.length; i++) {
  (function(idx) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#' + leds[idx].id).css('opacity', '1');
    }, 1000 * idx);
  })(i)
}
```

```css
.led {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .9s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="led" id="id1">TEST 1</div>
<div class="led" id="id2">TEST 2</div>
<div class="led" id="id3">TEST 4</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will set the opacity to each element one-by-one:

```
$(".led").each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(1000*index).queue(function() { 
      $(this).css('opacity' , '1');
     })
});
```

[image]